# How can I save an image to a JS variable and apply it to bg?

Tags: javascript, html, web-frontend

I have the following code:

```
let v = new Vibrant("https://source.unsplash.com/random/");

var bodyS = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style;
bodyS.background = 'url('+v._src+') no-repeat center center fixed';
```

Is there a way to save the image sent by unsplash to a variable so I can set it to the bg as well as use it for the following script instead of using this url again because unsplash sends a unique picture through the url everytime.

Comment: `v._src` shouldn't change -though, what is `Vibrant`

Comment: Variable `v` wouldn't change unless you assign it again to something else. By "use it for the following script", do you mean another JavaScript code on another web page? On the same page a global variable will do.

Comment: vibrant js helps us extract the prominent colors from the image. I intend to use them for the theme. [link]https://github.com/Vibrant-Colors/node-vibrant @JaromandaX

Comment: no, v._src is a url that sends a random picture from unsplash everytime its loaded. It isn't working on the same page @jpllosa

Comment: How about convert the image to base64 foramt and store it?

Comment: Not on the same page, you say. Ok, once you have the image you like, convert it to a base 64 string (`data:image/png;base64`), you can then save it on `localStorage`. On the other page, access the `localStorage` to get the image. Perhaps you could also try `URL.createObjectURL()`.

Comment: using `fetch('https://source.unsplash.com/random/', {method: 'HEAD'}).then(r => r.url)` you can now access the random url the site is responding with

Comment: Thanks @jpllosa

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comments already suggest, you can use `fetch`+`createObjectURL` to be able to re-use a single image. This snippet shows 4 random images at start (though the links had to be made unique, otherwise they would end up being the same because of caching). When you click the button however, it fetches a single new image and explicitly applies it to all the four `<img>` elements. The commented part would also replace the button and actually download the image on a second click, just the sandbox here on StackOverflow simply doesn't allow downloads.

```js
async function doThing(){
  let image=await fetch("https://source.unsplash.com/random/").then(res=>res.blob());
  let url=URL.createObjectURL(image);
  for(let img of document.getElementsByTagName("img"))
    img.src=url;
//  let a=document.createElement("a");
//  a.href=url;
//  a.download="test.jpg";
//  let button=document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
//  button.innerText="Download";
//  button.onclick=()=>a.click();
}
```

```css
img{
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?1">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?2">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?3">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?4">
<br>
<button onclick="doThing()">Clicky</button>
```

(If you want to test it elsewhere, a simple way to grab the code is to run the snippet, then right-click on some empty spot inside the frame, and use "View frame source" in Chrome, or "This Frame"/"View Frame Source" in Firefox)